# Spring Logging using custom annotation

Tags: spring, logging, spring-mvc, annotations

I want to write a custom annotation, say @loggable, which when declared at method level will display some logging message to the user about the current method. How would I go about this? Is this possible? How do I register this annotation with spring? Where do I write the logging logic?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Heres a good tutorial on how to do just that

[Custom Annotations with Spring AOP](http://cfossguy.blogspot.in/2008/09/extend-your-favorite-framework-with.html)

---

**EDIT 1**

Well heres a sample program i wrote, that accomplishes what you want.
This log methods , and even execution time of the Method.
Hope this helps.

**Loggable -- Custom Annotation Declaration**

```
package com.test.common.custom.annotation;
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Loggable {


   String message() default "Audit Message";

}
```

**LogManager -- This tells AspectJ what methods to intercept.**

```
package com.test.common.custom.annotation.pointcutmgr;
@Service
@Aspect
public class LogManager {

       @Pointcut("execution(* com.test.service.*.*(..))")
       public void auditLog() {}

       @Pointcut("execution(* com.test.service.*.*(..))")
       public void performanceLog(){

       }

}
```

**LogInterceptor - which advices what to do with the intercepted methods**

```
package com.test.common.custom.annotation;
@Service
@Aspect
public class LogInterceptor {
    @Before(value = "com.test.common.custom.annotation.pointcutmgr.LogManager.auditLog()"
            + "&& target(bean) "
            + "&& @annotation(com.test.common.custom.annotation.Loggable)"
            + "&& @annotation(logme)", argNames = "bean,logme")
    public void log(JoinPoint jp, Object bean, Loggable logme) {

        System.out.println(String.format("Log Message: %s", logme.message()));
        System.out.println(String.format("Bean Called: %s", bean.getClass()
                .getName()));
        System.out.println(String.format("Method Called: %s", jp.getSignature()
                .getName()));

    }

    @Around(value = "com.test.common.custom.annotation.pointcutmgr.LogManager.auditLog()"
            + "&& target(bean) "
            + "&& @annotation(com.test.common.custom.annotation.Loggable)"
            + "&& @annotation(logme)", argNames = "bean,logme")
    public void performanceLog(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Object bean, Loggable logme) throws Throwable {
        StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
        stopWatch.start();

        joinPoint.proceed();


        stopWatch.stop();

        StringBuffer logMessage = new StringBuffer();
        logMessage.append(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName());
        logMessage.append(".");
        logMessage.append(joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        logMessage.append("(");
        // append args
        Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            logMessage.append(args[i]).append(",");
        }
        if (args.length > 0) {
            logMessage.deleteCharAt(logMessage.length() - 1);
        }

        logMessage.append(")");
        logMessage.append(" execution time: ");
        logMessage.append(stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis());
        logMessage.append(" ms");
        System.out.println(logMessage.toString());


    }
}
```

**Heres how you use it**

Annotate the methods with `@Loggable` , this `will print logs and performance statistics`

```
@Loggable(message = "Add Cutomer is fired")
public void addCustomer(){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("addCustomer() is running ");
}
```

Comment: how do I intercept annotated @Controller,@Service,@Repository?how do I specify the pointcut in this case?